# WPF Change a rectangles points at runtime

Tags: wpf, path

I have a WPF app in which I need to programatically manipulate at runtime.

What I thought of doing is having a Path with 4 line segments like so:

```
          Canvas.Left="324" 
          Canvas.Top="247">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure IsClosed="True">
                    <LineSegment Point="0.5,0.5" />
                    <LineSegment Point="355.5,0.5" />
                    <LineSegment Point="355.5,229.5" />
                    <LineSegment Point="0.5,229.5" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

now, in my c# code I can do this:

```
        PathFigureCollection figures = (ThePath.Data as PathGeometry).Figures;

        Console.WriteLine("number of segments: " + figures[0].Segments.Count);

        LineSegment topLeft = figures[0].Segments[0] as LineSegment;
        LineSegment topRight = figures[0].Segments[1] as LineSegment;
        LineSegment bottomRight = figures[0].Segments[2] as LineSegment;
        LineSegment bottomLeft = figures[0].Segments[3] as LineSegment;

        topLeft.Point = new Point(topLeft.Point.X - 5, topLeft.Point.Y - 5);
        topRight.Point = new Point(topRight.Point.X + 45, topRight.Point.Y - 35);
        bottomRight.Point = new Point(bottomRight.Point.X, bottomRight.Point.Y + 35);
        bottomLeft.Point = new Point(bottomLeft.Point.X + 5, bottomLeft.Point.Y - 15);
```

But the problem is that when I change the topLeft LineSegment, is "seems" to add a point to the list of segments, i.e. the two LAST points (bottom left and top left) dont join up anymore...

I know im missing something small here, but please, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok I figured it out, I just needed to set the StartPoint on the PathFigure and change that point along with the line segments (of which I removed the first one, considering that I added the StartPoint).

Thanks.